# Prove the linear independence of $\{\sin^k(x)\}$, $ k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I have to prove the linear independence of $\{\sin^k(x)\}$, $ k\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

I haven't ideas for proving it. Linearly independent means that we cannot find solution of this :
$\sin^{k_1}(x) = \sum_{i\ne k_1} l_i \cdot \sin^{i}(x)$ where $l_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Usually Van der Monde determinant is helpful.

Comment: or you can consider to multiply by $sin(kx)$ and integrate in $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: @Exodd: i think you see $sin(nx)$ instead $sin(x)^{n}$

Comment: @Basti It's the same: $sin(x)^n$ can be written as sum of $sin(kx)$ for $k<n$, and you can prove that $sin(nx)$ appears only in $sin(x)^m$ with $m\ge n$

Comment: Is $\sin^k(x)$ the $k$th iterate or the $k$th power of $\sin(x)$?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\sin(x)^n = 0
$$
then the polynomial
$$
p(y) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n y^n 
$$
is of degree at most $N$, but $y=\sin(x)$ is a root for every $x$, so it has infinite roots. This means the polynomial is zero, or also said as $a_n=0$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you, but what means that $y = sin(x)$ is a root for every x. I mean root, why this polynom = 0 if $y = sin(x)$

Comment: because of the first relations of the sines. If you substitute $y=sin(x)$ you obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $\{f_k\circ g\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ are linearly independent, then so are $\{f_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$.

> Try $g=\arcsin$

Comment: Any additional condition on $g$?

Comment: @Clclstdnt No. (Note however that I use the $\{\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for *families*, not for *sets*). Assume $\sum a_k f_k=0$. Then $\sum a_k (f_k\circ g) = (\sum a_k f_k)\circ g=0\circ g=0$. Hence $a_k=0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbb{sin}^{l}(x)=\sum_{k=1,k\neq l}^{n}l_{k}\mathbb{sin}^{k}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x^{l}=\sum_{k=1,k\neq l}^{n}l_{k}x^{k}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. So, the last equality holds for every $x\in\mathbb{C}$ (by an analytic continuation). We deduce
$$x^{-1}=\sum_{k=1,k\neq l}^{n}l_{k}x^{k-l} $$
Integrating over the unitary circle we have $\frac{1}{2\pi i}=0$, because $z^{m}$ has a primitive for $m\neq-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $j,k\in \mathbb N_0$ with $j<k$ then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin^kx}{x^j}=0.$ And $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin^j x}{x^j}=1.$

Let $j_1,...,j_n$ be $n$ different members of $\mathbb N_0$ with $j_1=\min \{j_i:1\leq i\leq n\}.$

Let $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\sin^{(j_i)}x$  with each $A_i\ne 0.$

Then $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)x^{-j_1}=A_1\ne 0$ so we cannot have $g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $A$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}^*$ and 
$$ f_A(x)=\sum_{a\in A} c_a \sin^a(x) = 0,\qquad C=c_{\max A}\neq 0.\tag{1} $$
$f_A(x)$ can be written as a Fourier series, and if $M=\max A$ the coefficient of $e^{iMx}$ in such Fourier series just depends on $C$, being $\pm\frac{C}{2^M}$. By Parseval's theorem $0=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_A(x)^2\,dx $ is a fixed multiple of the sum of the squared coefficients of the previous Fourier series. In particular $C=0$, contradiction.